# Solat timetable

Tags: sharia

I have a question regarding prayer timetable for muslims . Let say , the time for Asar is 4.30pm . Based on islamic-rules, Is it possible for we to take the prayer time to be anywhere between 4.25pm or 4.35pm ? Or one must take the 4.30pm strictly ? Please kindly answer my question . Thank you and that's all from me .

Comment: The title of your question is just too vague and broad. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how the timetable was compiled.  Traditionally, prayer times were based on the position of the sun, not a particular time on a clock.  Prayer timetables, on the other hand, are often compiled for convenience rather than astronomical accuracy.

The start time for the *asr* prayer, for example, is [based on the length of an object's shadow](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10466/22): The shadow must be equal to the length of the object (or twice the length of the object by some schools) plus the length of the mid-day shadow, and the *asr* prayer can be prayed any time from then until sunset.

So it's possible that your *asr* time would be, for example, 4:00pm until 6:00pm, and the timetable just sets 4:30pm because it's convenient (maybe that's when most of your community normally gets off work).  However, it could also be that your *asr* time is 4:30pm until 7:00pm, and the timetable is exactly on the nose; praying before the recorded time in that case would be ill-advised.

Giving a general rule in this case is impossible; you'd be better off asking at a local masjid where someone might actually know how the timetable was compiled, or checking the position of the sun manually.  However, the general rule of "When you hear the *adhan*, go to prayer" would still apply, whether it's called according to the printed timetable or not.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that Asr prayer time is 4:30, that means that the prayer time starts at 4:30 and lasts until the start time of the following prayer , in our case Maghreb prayer.
Then you can not pray the Asr at 4:25, but you can pray it at 4:35

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please provide some reasoning to your answer. And go through [answer].